# Probability limits of consecutive runs in a fair coin toss

Tags: probability, probability-theory, limits

> Suppose a ***fair*** coin is tossed $n$ times. For $k \le n$, set $A_k$ as the event that these $n$ tosses yield a run of $k$ consecutive heads or tails. Show that for fixed $\varepsilon > 0$ holds:
>
> $$\mathbb{P}(A_k) \underset{n \to \infty}{\longrightarrow} \begin{cases} 0 \text{ if } k \ge (1+\varepsilon) \log_2 n, \\ 1 \text{ if } k \le (1-\varepsilon) \log_2 n. \end{cases}$$

Let $I_{k,i}$ be the indicator RV such that

$$I_{k,i} := \begin{cases} 1 \text{ if a consecutive run of length $k$ starts with the $i$-th toss,} \\ 0 \text{ else. } \end{cases}$$

Then we have (remember that it does not matter whether said run conists of heads or tails):

$$\mathbb{E}[I_{k,i}] = \mathbb{P}[I_{k,i} = 1] = \frac{1}{2^{k-1}}$$

Further, let $X$ be the RV that counts the number of distinct consecutive runs of length at least $k$. Then we have, by the fact that a consecutive run of length at least $k$ can only start with the first $n-k+1$ tosses, that

$$\mathbb{E}[X] = \sum_{i = 1}^{n-k+1} \mathbb{E}\left[I_{k,i}\right] = \sum_{i = 1}^{n-k+1}\mathbb{P}[I_{k,i} = 1] = (n-k+1)\frac{1}{2^{k-1}}$$

Now, if $k \ge (1+\varepsilon)\log_2 n$ we have by Markov's inequality that

$$\mathbb{P}\left[ A_k \right] = \mathbb{P}\left[ X \ge 1 \right] \le \mathbb{E}\left[ X \right] = (n-k+1)\frac{1}{2^{k-1}} \le (n-k+1)\frac{2}{n^{1+\varepsilon}} \underset{n \to \infty}{\longrightarrow} 0.$$

For the part $k \le (1-\varepsilon)\log_2 n$ we note that

$$\mathbb{P}\left[ A_k^C \right] = \mathbb{P}\left[ X = 0 \right].$$

From the lecture I know the following theorem, which comes in handy:

> Theorem ("Second moment method for a sum of indicator RVs"): Let $X = X_1 + \ldots + X_n$ be a sum of indicator RVs with $\mathbb{E}\left[ X \right] \ne 0$. Then
>
> $$\mathbb{P}\left[ X= 0 \right] \le \frac{1}{\mathbb{E}\left[ X \right] } + \frac{\sum_{i \ne j} Cov \left[ X_i,X_j \right] }{\mathbb{E}\left[ X \right]^2} $$
>
> Corollary:Let $X = X_1 + \ldots + X_n$ be a sum of indicator RVs with $\mathbb{E}\left[ X \right] \ne 0$. If every pair $X_i, X_j$ is either independent or negatively corrolated, i.e. $Cov \left[X_i, X_j \right] \le 0$, then
>
> $$\mathbb{P}\left[ X= 0 \right] \le \frac{1}{\mathbb{E}\left[ X \right] }$$

Still work in progress: As suggested by Michh in the comments we now compute:

$$Cov \left[ I_{k,i}, I_{k,j} \right] = \begin{cases}0 &\text{ if $k > \lvert i-j \rvert$,} \\ < 0 &\text{ if $k \le \lvert i-j \rvert$}\end{cases},$$

so the Corollary is applicable and we can write:

$$1 - \mathbb{P}\left[ A_k \right] = \mathbb{P}\left[ X = 0 \right] \le \frac{1}{\mathbb{E}\left[ X \right]} = \frac{2^{k-1}}{n-k+1} \le \frac{n^{1-\varepsilon}}{2(n-k+1)} \underset{n \to \infty}{\longrightarrow} 0,$$

so $\mathbb{P}\left[ A_k \right] \longrightarrow 1$.

Comment: So for $n=100$ and $k=1$ the probability of $A_1$ is $\frac 12$?

Comment: You are right, I made an extensive edit.

Comment: To compute the covariance, you can distinguish two cases: first case is when the distance between $i$ and $j$ is greater than $k$ so that $I_{k,i}$ and $I_{k,j}$ are independent. Second case is when they are at distance $d<k$, then the product $I_{k,i}I_{k,j}$ is simply the indicator $I_{d+k,\min(i,j)}$.

Comment: I still have my problems in the new situation, please help. First of all, we have a relation of the shape $$P(A_k)\overset{n\to\infty}\longrightarrow\text{(something)}\ ,$$ where the limit is taken for $n$ only, but that "something" makes $k$ also move somehow with $n$. So $k$ is in fact some $k(n)$, not a fixed $k$. OK, i can accept this, and in this case let us consider the sequence $k(n)=n$, which is at any rate matching the case $k(n)\ge (1+\epsilon)\log_2n$ for $\epsilon=1/2$. I would expect a zero probability in the limit, also as shown, but the claim has a one. For the other case...

Comment: ... for the other case, let $$k(n)=(1-\epsilon)\log 2 n\ ,$$ if i understand correctly, we have to compute$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\Bbb P(\ A_{k(n)}\ )\ ,$$and show the limit is one. Here, $A_k$ is the event that there are at least (floor or ceil of) $k$ consecutive occurrences of the same face among all paths of $H$ and $T$ of length $n$.

Comment: @dan_fulea: I am very sorry, there was a typo in the problem statement; I fixed it.

Comment: No problem, thanks for the quick fix, i think we have an interesting question, and getting it right is a long term profit for the community!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can avoid the second moment calculation because of the independence structure baked in to the problem. Observe that $I_{k,1}, I_{k,k+1}, I_{k,2k+1},\cdots, I_{k,k \lfloor n/k\rfloor + 1}$ are all independent. Since each is $1$ with probability at least $2^{-(k-1)},$ the probability that none of these is $1$ is $ (1-2^{-(k-1)})^{\lfloor n/k\rfloor} \le \exp(- \lfloor n/k\rfloor 2^{-(k-1)}),$ and this dominates the probability of $A_k^c$. If $n$ is such that $\lfloor n/(1-\varepsilon) \log n\rfloor > n/(2\log_2 n),$ (which is true for all $n$ large enough, since $n/\log n \to \infty$), then we can further bound this from above by $$\exp\left(- \frac{n}{\log_2 n} \cdot n^{-(1-\varepsilon)} \right) = \exp( - n^{\varepsilon}/\log_2(n)) \to 0, $$ and you're done.

---

The second moment calculation yields a slightly sharper result. Let me just write $I_{m}$ instead of $I_{k,m}$, and let's consider the covariance between $I_{m}$ and $I_{m+j}$ for some $j \in [0:k-1]$ (recall that for larger $j$, they are independent, so have covariance $0$). Suppose $I_m = 1$. Then $I_{m+j}$ can happen only if $X_{m+k+1},\cdots, X_{m+j+k}$ take the same value as $X_m$, which happens with probability $2^{-j}$, and so $\mathbb{E}[I_{m+j}|I_m = 1] =2^{-j}$. But since if $I_m = 0, I_mI_{m+j} = 0,$ we get $$\mathbb{E}[I_m I_{m+j}] = \mathbb{E}[ \mathbb{E}[I_{m+j}|I_m = 1] P(I_m = 1)]  = 2 \cdot 2^{-(j+k)},$$ giving $\mathrm{Cov}(I_m, I_{m+j}) = 2^{-(k-1)} (2^{-j} - 2^{-(k-1)}).$ Note also that for $j < k-10,$ this is basically just $2^{-k} \cdot 2^{-j}$ up to some constant factor.

So, we get $$ \sum_{i=1}^{n-k+1} \sum_{j \neq i} \mathrm{Cov}(I_i I_j) =2\sum_{i = 1}^{n-k+1} \sum_{j = 1}^{\min(k, n-k+1-i)} \mathrm{Cov}(I_i I_{i+j}) \\ \le 2\sum_{i = 1}^{n-k + 1}\sum_{j = 1}^{k-1} 2^{-(k-1)} (2^{-j} - 2^{-(k-1)}) \le 4n 2^{-k}.$$ You can refine these calculations a little, but you'll end up with the same behaviour up to some constant factor, because the covariance is roughly $2^{-(k+j)}$ for $j < k-10,$ and so the sum has to be at least $\sum_{j = 1}^{k-10} 2^{-(k+j)},$ and since $k$ is large, $\sum_{1}^{k -10} 2^{-j} > 1/2.$ The advantage over the crude independence based calculation is that that essentially bounds $\mathrm{Cov}(I_m I_{m+j})$ by $1$ for $j < k,$ and so this refined calculation is saving you a factor of $k$.

Of course, $\mathbb{E}[X]^2 = 4n^2 2^{-2k},$ so the second moment bound works out to $$ P(A_k^c) \le \frac{2^k}{n} + \frac{2^k}{n}.$$ This gives a slight refinement: if $k \le \log_2(n) - \omega(1)$ then $P(A_k) \to 1$. You can observe that the upper bound $P(A_k) \le 2n2^{-k}$ also yields that if $k = \log_2(n) + \omega(1),$ then $P(A_k) \to 0$, so this pair of results sharpens the cutoff to an arbitrarily slowly growing window, instead of a window of size $o(\log n)$ that you get through the cruder calculation.